# update trigger when updating table through SSMS

Tags: triggers, azure-sql-database, ssms

I have an update trigger that does what it needs to do: update a datefield triggered by an after update trigger.

However, when I edit the contents of a table through SSMS (right-click - Edit top 200 rows) it gives me a message that the row couldn't be committed. The error:

```
The data in row x was not committed.
Eror message: The row value(s) updated or deleted either do not make the row unique or they alter multiple ows(2rows).
```

If i disable the trigger  an update through the interface works  just fine.
The same upate through an TSQL update statement works fine when the trigger is activated (and trigger does what it needs to do)

What is causing this behaviour and how can I have ànd the trigger ànd update through the interface?
Lots of my updates are queries that contain single quotes so it is easier to paste them than write an update statement to update them)

Comment: Don't use the "edit" feature, is the *real* solution here. It's full of "features". Use an `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: @larnu Any Idea what causes this behaviour?

Comment: As i said, *"**It's full of "features"**. Use an `UPDATE` statement."* Then the "feature" won't happen.

Comment: I was hoping for a little more information

Comment: are you updating the table with the trigger in the trigger?

Comment: No, the issue is that triggers apparently just don't play nice when using the edit functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that triggers apparently just don't play nice when using the edit functionality

Comment: Is there no other solution to this problem? I don't like this one at all.